# Get multiple custom type posts at once in edit.php?post_type request

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm planing a custom post type functionality for my theme and need to be able to display more than just one `post_type` in a admin overview table. That request I imagine might look like `edit.php?post_type[]=theme_slide_nivo&post_type[]=theme_slide_other`. Haven't actually tried that but i'm pretty confident it won't work. So guys, is it possible to achieve such result without hacking core?

Comment: You should never have to hack to core. What exactly are you trying to accomplish, editing 2 custom post types at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it out to get an idea of the problems you will run into. The following code allows you to specify multiple post types with the `multi_post_type` parameter:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse12970_pre_get_posts' );
function wpse12970_pre_get_posts( &$wp_query )
{
    if ( is_admin() && array_key_exists( 'multi_post_type', $_GET ) ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'post_type', $_GET['multi_post_type'] );
        add_filter( 'the_posts', 'wpse12970_the_posts', 10, 2 );
    }
}

function wpse12970_the_posts( $posts, &$wp_query )
{
    $wp_query->set( 'post_type', $GLOBALS['post_type'] );
    return $posts;
}
```

The first problem was that the global `$post_type` should be a single type, otherwise other functions break. So we "smuggle" the multiple post types in under another name, and remove them again after the query ran.

The counter at the top of the list and the custom columns are based on only one post type. If there are many results paging will probably break.

If you want to do this, you should create your own list class, a child of `WP_List_Table`, like `WP_Posts_List_Table` but then for multiple post types. Because `edit.php` loads this table by default and I see no way to intercept it, you should create your own replacement of `edit.php` in your plugin and use that. I think it is doable, and probably interesting, but a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Just picking up the comment above and let you know that I was able to use that code to filter multiple post types with it, simply replace:

`$wp_query->set( 'post_type', $_GET['multi_post_type'] );`

with

`$wp_query->set( 'post_type', explode(',',$_GET['multi_post_type']) );`

Simply use the URL with a comma-separated string like
`&multi_post_type=page,post`

Comment: The other way to do that would be to use array-type query string parameters e.g. `&multi_post_type[]=page&multi_post_type[]=post`, then WordPress will automatically make an array. Which I think is is what OP is doing in the question.