# List All Post Types in Admin view using /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=

Tags: admin, post-type

I have successfully created a custom post type. I'm trying to construct a URL which points to a combined listing of posts of all post types on the view all posts page in the admin view.

I can construct a URL which points to posts of specific post types, eg 
`http://<mysite>//wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=my_post_type`. But I can't find a way of listing posts of all post types.

Is it possible to use the `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=` slug to point to a page listing posts of all post types? Or, how else can I build a URL which will?

Comment: Are you saying you want a page that lists all of the different post type entries? Or a page that lists all the posts from a specific post type?

Comment: A page that lists all of the different post type entries

Comment: You're trying to achieve this on the admin side of things, correct? Where the admin can edit every post of every post type in one place?

Comment: Yes, this would be a listing in the admin side. The only thing my custom post type does differently from the normal post type is it injects some text into $content. I don't need to separate the different post types. It is better that the editor managing the posts can see all the posts in one listing.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types#Output_a_list_of_all_public_custom_post_types - you'll need your own page to construct the table, but with the post types you could run a query for all of that type.

Comment: Make a copy of edit.php and customise the query? Hmm, hadn't thought of that. Bit of a faff though. Was hoping for a steer on how to create my own `edit.php?post_type=all` URL. But thanks, that's given me an avenue to explore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way this could work would be `?post_type=any` based on [WP_Query post_type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters) params.

But the context is the problem, the `edit.php` page requires a specific post type, to display and edit only one [$post_type_object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_object) which returns, for each post_type, only one singular label, one plural label and so many others individual properties.

These are not only technical blocking problems but also conceptual ones which make this impossible to be done.

Personally, I would research on "How to build a custom admin page" with a query like `post_type=any`

Comment: Just been arriving at a similiar conclusion. Actually found a duplicate of this question from 5 years ago here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12970/get-multiple-custom-type-posts-at-once-in-edit-phppost-type-request[/link]. Same issues then.

Comment: yep, that is similar, I couldn't find it tho

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote your answer, I don't have enough rep (2 to go!). But thanks for your help

Comment: Don't worry, I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pre_get_posts` with a `$_GET` parameter and piggyback on the current post type - for example, say we're viewing *all* editable posts in the admin panel, we can add a parameter `showall=true` and show all post types:

```
/**
 * Show all post editable post types
 *
 * @param WP_Query Object $query
 *
 * @return void
 */
function show_all_posttypes( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    if( isset( $_GET, $_GET['showall'] ) && true == $_GET['showall'] ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'any' );
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_all_posttypes' );
```

If you want to limit the post types by some way or another you can use [`get_post_types()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) function and pass the returned post types into the `post_type` parameter as an array().

We can even add this as a subpage admin link for ease of access:

```
/**
 * Show All Post Types Link
 * - Subpage of "All Pages"
 *
 * @return void
 */
function show_all_posttypes_link() {
    add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=page', '', 'All Post Types', 'edit_posts', '/edit.php?post_type=page&showall=true');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'show_all_posttypes_link' );
```

You could keep extending this on and on to customize the column outputs and such but this is the gist of it.